# To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect

Tags: node.js

When I run a simple NodeJS project to upload data to a database using MongoDB, I get the following errors:

(node:3556) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version.  To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share some code so we can best help you. There is information about how to ask a good question in the help centre: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using mongo to connect try using:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@domain.com:port/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

If you're using mongoose, use something like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@domain.com:27017/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

You could also use something like this:

```
const config = {
  autoIndex: false,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
};
return mongoose.connect(uri, config);
```

As explained by lineus:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6667

Comment: I found that I had to also add "useUnifiedTopology: true" to the config object to get mine working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside your layout file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDatabase', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Then you can create your Schema layout, for example:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String, 
    last_name: String
});
```

Comment: Don't you think it is better practice to put the mongoose connection in **app.js** with other configurations? Well, just thinking out loud.